# Reset png cache in react native

Tags: react-native

When I add some image from my assets folder using require, the image is apparently being taken from a folder `.png-cache` , but react native probably has bad paths stored in them because I get an error wherever I've used the same file as the image source.
My code is:

```
        <Image
          source={require('@assets/images/thunder.svg')}
          height={20}
          width={20}
          resizeMode={'contain'}
          style={styles.actionButtonIconStyle}
        />
```

The image doesn't show up and the console shows:

```
Error: Asset not found: C:\Users\<project path>\src\assets\images\.png-cache\thunder-31748fee8334daf886e2bea1259f80c9@3x.png for platform: android
    at getAbsoluteAssetRecord (C:\Users\<project path>\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:110:11)
    at async getAsset (C:\Users\<project path>\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:238:18)
    at async Server._processSingleAssetRequest (C:\Users\<project path>\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:352:20)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\<project path>\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:427:7)
```

Not sure why the current paths are not valid. Is it possible to make it so that the old cached paths are forgotten and new cache file generated?

What I've tried:

- I renamed one image file and it worked but I wouldn't want to rename all the files, looking for a way to reset the cache.
- I looked at the solution in [Reset internal android image cache in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603434/reset-internal-android-image-cache-in-react-native) but I can't have dynamic paths in `require` so this solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by resetting the react native cache with the command:

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 1):

I see first time using like @asset...

In my code i everytime use like this:

```
<Image
          source={require('../assets/images/thunder.svg')}
          height={20}
          width={20}
          resizeMode={'contain'}
          style={styles.actionButtonIconStyle}
        />
```

am i missunderstanding what you need?

Comment: I have defined `@assets` as `./assets` in my jsconfig file. And no, using it like `/assets/images/thunder.svg` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MaheshBansod is it start with dots? (..)